# Perl regex splitting with nested commas

Tags: regex, perl

I have a key,value pair string where the pairs are comma separated but the values have nested commas.

ex.

```
"key1|val1,key2|val2_a,val2_b,val2_c,key3|val3"
```

I want to break this out into a hash and have hacked it with the following:

```
my $str = "key1|val1,key2|val2_a,val2_b,val2_c,key3|val3";
my @vars = split(/([^,\s]+)\|/ ,$str);
my @arr = splice @vars, 1;
my %hash  = @arr;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

which gives me:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'key2' => 'val2_a,val2_b,val2_c,',
      'key1' => 'val1,',
      'key3' => 'val3'
    };
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this. I figure it can be done with one regex but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a positive lookahead in the split.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "key1|val1,key2|val2_a,val2_b,val2_c,key3|val3";
my %hash = split(/\||,(?=\w+\|)/, $str);

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'val2_a,val2_b,val2_c',
          'key1' => 'val1',
          'key3' => 'val3'
        };
```

I've found that this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) does a good job explaining look arounds.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty comes in deciding where the list of values ends for each key. Most obviously it can be at the end of the string or, more obscurely, where another key|value pair starts. (This is a dreadful design. Can it be fixed before you find anything more difficult to solve?)

This solution works by defining a regex for a "key" string (anything but a pipe, comma, or whitespace) and then using it to build the pattern for a complete key|value pair which ends either at the end of a string or where another "comma - key - pipe" sequence begins.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'key1|val1,key2|val2_a,val2_b,val2_c,key3|val3';

my $key_re = qr/ [^|,\s]+ /x;

my @pairs = $s =~ / $key_re \| [^|\s]+ (?= \z | , $key_re \| )/gx;

print "$_\n" for @pairs;
```

**output**

```
key1|val1
key2|val2_a,val2_b,val2_c
key3|val3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Works great. I wish I could change the design but I'm just consuming the data.